# Extjs4.1 - Submit Valid form within hidden field has allowblank false

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a form panel with dynamic items. Some items has hidden like example:

```
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Field 1',
            name: 'theField'
        },{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Field 2',
            name: 'theField'
        },{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Field 3',
            name: 'theField',
            hidden: true,
            allowBlank : false
        }]
```

But when i submit my form like

```
            if (form.isValid()) {
                alert('submit');
            }else alert('fail');
```

that will check all field, and my form will not submit. 
Has anyway to valid form (only field is shown) ? how to do that thanks

Here is my example to check **http://jsfiddle.net/jZYcQ/**

Answer (score 6):

As you've said, hidden fields will still be validated. Instead, you should disable the field, which means it won't be submitted, but also won't be included in validation.

Comment: Indeed, I set both hidden and disabled and it works like a charm! Thanks bro! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hidden fields are validated. To disable or skip validation for hidden fields, you can set 'skipValidation' to true. Also, set 'allowBlank' to true if that is set too.

So, normally when a field is defined and you've added validations on it, setting skipValidation to true will disable form submit validations for that field. However, it does not disable the allowBlank validation. You still cannot set your field to be empty on submit. Hence, you would require both if your field has other validations on it apart from making the field required. Reset them when fields are shown..

```
//View
xtype:'textfield',
allowBlank:false,
validator: function(){
  //custom validation 
}
...

//Controller
function(){
...
   form.down("#field").skipValidation = true;
   form.down("field").allowBlank = true;
...
}
```